# Delete all commits after a specific commit

Tags: git

I have the following commit history (everything is pushed) where I want to discard all commits in the marked spot e.g all commits from (and including) `e603105` and forward.

[image]

Comment: If you want to discard last 3 commits
git reset HEAD~3
git push -f origin... not so nice if others are using origin...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can hard [reset](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) back

```
git reset --hard ff61726
```

This is considered re-writing history so then it would require a force [push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)

```
git push -f
```

Comment: Would it remove those commits or just create a new commit at HEAD with `ff61726`?

Comment: This would remove those commits from your current branch.

Comment: You should probably never ever use `-f` with `git push`. If you need to force something, use `--force-with-lease` instead which has some safeguards for shooting your leg off.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot directly *delete* commits from git, but you can *stop a branch pointing at them*, and they will eventually be deleted by a "garbage collection" routine.

To *move a branch pointer*, you can use [git reset](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset).

Specifically, if "some-branch" currently points at ac033d7, and you run this:

```
git checkout some-branch
git reset --hard ff61726
```

Now "some-branch" points at commit ff61726, but commit ac033d7 still exists, and will only be garbage collected once nothing points to it any more.

One of the things that will probably still point to it is any *remote* copy of the "some-branch" branch, e.g. on Github/BitBucket/GitLab. To move that branch, you need to perform a ["force push"](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push):

```
git push --force-with-lease
```